# unrecognized selector sent to instance - analysis

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

[image]

I am getting this error by simply filling an `NSMutableArray` in `TableView`'s `cell` in the **Highlighted** line of code.

[image: 1]

Whereas the First line is executing properly. I tried putting `BooksDataForTable[a]` from 1st line to 2nd line instead of `BookAuthors[a]` and it executed successfully. But i get something interesting while looking at debugin area. Here it is.

[image]

You can see the difference between both the `NSMutableArray`'s and that must the reason for the error. Actually the `BooksDataForTable` is filled by the `NSString`'s while the `BooksAuthors` is filled by an `NSArray` but unfortunately i'am unable to understand that why it could be the reason behind this error!

Comment: Please post console output and code as text by copy & paste. Do not post as images.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i didn't think it as wrong!

Comment: The problem with images is it makes it harder to reference the information when posting comments and answers. And many times (not really in this case), images are harder to read. It's always best to post info as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 5):

`BookAuthors` is an array of arrays, not an array of strings.

You would need a line like:

```
cell.detailText.label = [BookAuthors[a] firstObject];
```

However, it seems all of the arrays in `BookAuthors` each only have one element. So you are probably building the array incorrectly.

Side note - it is standard practice to name methods and variables to start with lowercase letters and class names to start with uppercase letters.

Comment: But i'm storing `NSString` in `BookAuthors` by running a loop and returning different `NSString`.

Comment: You think you are, but you are not. Look at the debugger output. Notice that each element of `BooksAuthors` is an array. The error makes it clear as well. You appear to have a bug in how you populate `BooksAuthors`. That would be a good new question. Close this one and post a new question with details about how you populate `BooksAuthors` and how you want an array of strings instead of an array of arrays of string.